# check is the contact email address correct

Tags: grammar, email

someone give me the email address made contact another one,
but I can't get reply. so I wanna ask:

```
...
Is the email address to xxx correct?  
Because I can't get response from him.
...
```

is there something wrong with the grammer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just Pretty close but not entirely correct, first of all, please remove 'to' in line one

> Is the email address to xxx correct?

it does not fit. Next, the grammar of your reply depends on what xxx represents.

Lets say you are trying to contact a 'Paul' and the email id was paul@xyz.com then

Scenario 1 , if the xxx in your question represents the person 'Paul' i.e xxx = Paul then it will go like

> Is the email address for Paul correct? Because I can't get a reply from him

Scenario 2 , if the xxx in your question represents the email ID 'paul@xyz.com' i.e xxx = paul@xyz.com then it will go like

> Is the email address paul@xyz.com correct? Because I can't get a reply from him.

So it depends on what the xxx represents in your question.